# Linux C client receives 0 bytes while server is not sending anything

Tags: c, sockets

I got a client and server application, and I'm observing strange behavior:

The client sends data, and after 80 microsecond executes recvfrom, which returns 0,
server receives data and sends response  after client executes recvfrom. This is only one send from server.

Question: Is this a problem with the code of client or the code is ok? 
From manual page of revcfrom I can see that recvfrom returns 0 when peer closes connection - but I don't see any closed connections on the server's side - I did strace of server and strace of client:

client side:

```
16:06:08.206571 sendto(16, "initialize\r\n", 12, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 12
16:06:08.206654 recvfrom(16, "", 256, 0, NULL, NULL) = 0
```

server side:

```
16:06:08.209998 recvfrom(11, "initialize\r\n", 256, 0, NULL, NULL) = 12
16:06:08.215474 sendto(11, "1\n", 2, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 2
```

I'm bit lost where problem lays...

Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Comment: Is this UDP protocol?

Answer (score 0):

recvfrom()/recv() is the same regardless of being server or client, so 0(closed connection) means the same thing.

Comment: but what if i dont see any close on server side ?

Comment: You have to be looking for it. Going off of your example your client sends, your server receives, then your server sends and then your client was suppose to receive. If you don't have another socket related function called after all that, you won't see it. Sockets can be pretty tricky to troubleshoot, almost like multithreading. If you just throw in another recv() or recfrom() on the server(only for the purposes) of troubleshooting), you should actually get a value less than 0.

Comment: Oh, and look up setting and printing errno. I can't even begin to explain how beneficial it will be to you early on.